# Invalid parameter Facebook video ad creative in Facebook Marketing API

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, facebook-marketing-api

I am getting the same error while creating Ad Creative via Facebook Marketing API. I followed their guide but doesn't work. [Facebook video ad creative reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/videoads)

```
    $config = Config::get('facebook');
    $data['account_id'] = 'act_'.$config['ad_account_id'];
    $data['page_id'] = $config['page_id'];

    // Init facebook
    $api = Api::init($config['app_id'], $config['app_secret'], $config['access_token']);

    // Create product catalog
    $product_catalog = new ProductCatalog(null,  $config['business_id']);
    $product_catalog->setData(array(
        ProductCatalogFields::NAME => "Catalog",
    ));
    $product_catalog->create();

    $product_catalog_id = $product_catalog->id;

    // Setup Feed
    $product_feed = new ProductFeed(null, $product_catalog_id);
    $product_feed->setData(array(
        ProductFeedFields::NAME => 'Campaign Feed',
        ProductFeedFields::SCHEDULE => array(
            ProductFeedScheduleFields::INTERVAL => 'DAILY',
            ProductFeedScheduleFields::URL => 'http://example.com/facebook/dpa_product_catalog_sample_feed.csv',
            ProductFeedScheduleFields::HOUR => 22,
        ),
    ));
    $product_feed = $product_feed->create();

    // Create  Product Set
    $product_set = new ProductSet(null,  $product_catalog_id);
    $product_set->setData(array(
        ProductFeedFields::NAME => 'All Product',
    ));
    $product_set->create();

    $data['product_set_id'] = $product_set->id;

    $video = new Advideo(null, $data['account_id']);
    $video->{AdVideoFields::SOURCE} = public_path().'/facebook/video-demo.mp4';
    $video->create();

    $video_data = new AdCreativeVideoData();
    $video_data->setData(array(
      AdCreativeVideoDataFields::IMAGE_URL => 'http://example.com/facebook/resize-image.jpg',
      AdCreativeVideoDataFields::VIDEO_ID => $video->id,
      AdCreativeVideoDataFields::CALL_TO_ACTION => array(
        'type' => AdCreativeCallToActionTypeValues::LIKE_PAGE,
        'value' => array(
          'page' => $data['page_id'],
        ),
      ),
    ));

    $object_story_spec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
    $object_story_spec->setData(array(
      AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => $data['page_id'],
      AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::VIDEO_DATA => $video_data,
    ));
```

Above these code working and return response but when I call ad creative, the API return "Invalid parameter"

```
    $creative = new AdCreative(null, $data['account_id']);
    $creative->setData(array(
      AdCreativeFields::NAME => 'Video Ad Template Creative Sample',
      AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
      AdCreativeFields::PRODUCT_SET_ID => $data['product_set_id'],
    ));

    $creative->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be your issue is in creating `AdCreativeVideoData`.

search for line

```
AdCreativeVideoDataFields::IMAGE_URL => public_path().'/facebook/resize-image.jpg',
```

Here `IMAGE_URL`  requires url path like http://example.com/myimage.jpg. You are giving directory path that might cause problem.

If your image is not directly accessible from URL then you should create IMAGE_HASH. For this see below.

```
try {
        $image = new AdImage(null, $data['account_id']);
        $image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = public_path().'/facebook/resize-image.jpg';

        $image->create();
        // Image_hash = $image->hash
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error message: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n" . "<br/>";
        echo 'Error Code: ' . $e->getCode() . "<br/>";
    }
```

And replace IMAGE_URL to IMAGE_HASH in your `AdCreativeVideoData` like this

```
$video_data = new AdCreativeVideoData();
    $video_data->setData(array(
      AdCreativeVideoDataFields::IMAGE_HASH => $image->hash,
      AdCreativeVideoDataFields::VIDEO_ID => $video->id,
      AdCreativeVideoDataFields::CALL_TO_ACTION => array(
        'type' => AdCreativeCallToActionTypeValues::LIKE_PAGE,
        'value' => array(
          'page' => $data['page_id'],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I replace IMAGE_URL to IMAGE_HASH with your reference code but the same error came from AdCreative.

Comment: Same problem here !! please any one can solve this issue ! :(